# Will a "Mac format" iPod nano (2gen) work on a PC?

Tags: ipod, windows, ipod-nano

I have an old 8GB iPod nano (2nd gen, I think).  When I plug it into iTunes, one of the things on the status page is "Format: Macintosh".

I no longer use this iPod, so I'm thinking of giving it to my parents, but I don't think they have a Mac.

Will this iPod be able to work with a Windows PC?

Answer (score 6):

No, but if you connect it to a Windows machine and restore the iPod using iTunes, it will reformat it to work with Windows. If you want to learn a bit more, read this Apple support article: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1335?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **Yes** : It will work with a PC. You just have to format it on that platform.